# [Silverlight]Converting query result into a list

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization

I'm trying to store my query result into XML in isolated storage application. 
Here's my source in regards of the query, But the problem is I cannot cast the Productlist into a List or Iqueryable so I can pass the data to Save_Product() method. Thanks in advance for the help guys.

```
 private void loadProductCombobox()
    {
        productDomainContext = new ProductDS();
        EntityQuery<product> bb = from b in productDomainContext.GetProductsQuery() select b;
        LoadOperation<product> res = productDomainContext.Load(bb, new Action<LoadOperation<product>>(loadProductComboboxcompleted), true);

    }
    private void loadProductComboboxcompleted(LoadOperation<product> obj)
    {
       selectProductComboBox.ItemsSource= productDomainContext.products;

     ****************Issue causing line*************
       IEnumerable<product> productList = (IEnumerable<product>)productDomainContext.products;
       List<product> productlist2 = (List<product>)productList;
       Save_Product(productlist2);        
     *******************   

    }

    public static void Save_Product(List<product> product)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("Product.XML", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<product>));
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, product);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I have also tried to do this:

```
    private void loadProductCombobox()
    {
        productDomainContext = new ProductDS();
        EntityQuery<product> bb = from b in productDomainContext.GetProductsQuery() select b;
        LoadOperation<product> res = productDomainContext.Load(bb, new Action<LoadOperation<product>>(loadProductComboboxcompleted), true);

    }
    private void loadProductComboboxcompleted(LoadOperation<product> obj)
    {
       selectProductComboBox.ItemsSource= productDomainContext.products;
       Save_Product(productDomainContext.products);



    }

    public static void Save_Product(EntitySet<product> product)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("Product.XML", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EntitySet<product>));
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, product);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

It says it cannot be serialized becuase it has to be ienumerable

Comment: I dont understand your problem - you "cannot cast to List<product>" so why cant you use productList.ToList() ?

Comment: It gave me this error:There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InventoryApplications.Web.EntityDataModel.product]'.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the line casting `productDomainContext.Products` to `Products`? Are they both of the exact same type, or are you mapping between two similar classes? If it is with the cast from `IEnumerable` to `List` you could also try `List<Product> productList2 = new List<Product>(productList);`

Comment: No mashton. The error occurs when it tries to serialize the list.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out why the serializer cannot work directly from entity, but I worked around it by making a list of the copy of model then I serialized it.

Hopefully this will help.